# How to get json api that doesnt read every time the best way

Tags: php, json, time, response, delay

I have this function in php which tries to read a json api and it can take up to 10 attempts to read it and I want to send that response to view, but the function takes to long to run and will often not work, how can I make the code run better

Edit Changed the question

Its basically this now, it kinda works but I would like to have a better alternative.

```
$getjson = null;

for($i =0; i < 10; $i++){
try{
 $getjson = json_decode(file_get_contents('url'));
 if(array_key_exists('index', $getjson)) break;
  }catch(\Exception $e){}
}

return $getjson;
```

Comment: This is not how php works. It is synchronous by nature, so you function will not complete before your api return a response. Are you sure your functions completes before that?

Comment: Please show your code and methods you've tried. It's virtually impossible to guide you in the right direction without knowing how you're building what you're doing. I'd recommend reading [Help on asking Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added code example

Comment: Just to clarify - are you saying that it regularly runs the file_get_contents ONCE, and even if that fails, it returns the response? If so, [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) actually returns false if it fails. So, to ensure it has a content, store a variable outside of a while-loop that file_get_content writes to. While that is not true (or compares to true, meaning it has content), you continue fetching.

Comment: It will run and return null if it doesnt read anything right now. Do you have any code examples on how to improve the fetching of json?

Answer (score 0):

You say your code runs, but returns null if it does not read anything. The below code will avoid that specific scenario.

```
$get = null;

while($get == null || $get === false) {
    $get = file_get_contents('url');
}

return json_decode($get);
```

NOTE: This code *can* technically be an endless loop, assuming it constantly evaluates this way. It would be **very** advisable to have some kind of check to ensure that the script isn't killed by the web server prematurely, and that it does not continue running forever. I would have a set limit for how many times you're actually supposed to keep trying to fetch, and run that as a for-loop instead. Then make sure to have a fallback if all iterations still failed.

Something like this would be more advisable:

```
$get = null;
$limit = 100;
$i = 0;

do {
    $get = file_get_contents('url');
    $i++;

} while(($get == null || $get === false) && $i < $limit);

return json_decode($get);
```

Finally, if you don't like do-while, you can do it with a single for as well.

```
$get = null;

for($i = 0; ($get == null || $get === false) && $i < $limit; $i++) {
    $get = file_get_contents('url');
}

return json_decode($get);
```